# Copy Pivot Table to Outlook then Send

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I need help on how to add pivot table to my email body. Here is my current code.

```
Sub EmailSend()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    olMail.To = "c_dpal###in@###.com.##"
    olMail.CC = "c_dpal###in@###.com.##"
    olMail.Subject = Workbooks("### Report").Sheets("####Perf").Range("J3")
    olMail.Body = "Good Day Ms ###," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please see performance as of today:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Regards," & vbCrLf & "####"
    olMail.Send

End Sub
```

Currently, I have no idea how to do it and I seem to can't find how to do it online. Appreciate you big help. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, that's an interesting problem. Probably the simplest (?) approach would be to render the pivot table as an HTML table, and insert THAT into the body of your `MailItem` object. (I am assuming your `MailItem` object supports HTML automatically: if not, that's another thing you'll have to figure out how to make happen.)

Comment: This code you've pasted is from a VBA macro in your spreadsheet, correct?  I am assuming that your Pivot Table already exists in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Yup Ann, Correct. Thanks! Will research on this solution you mentioned. Thank you Ann!

Comment: I don't know whether it can be done programmatically, but since you can copy and paste Excel ranges into other documents, and they'll behave like HTML tables, it ought to be possible to copy a range and convert it into HTML. I don't know where you'd look for that functionality, but it ought to be there somewhere!

Comment: Best of luck!  

Comment: Hi it's not so easy to do but can be done. Here is [YT_Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjbvTngTr-M) showing how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I once used the [RangeToHTML](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) from Ron de Bruin and it work quite well.

Put this code on a standard module and try it. I used two ranges, one for the pivot filters and the other for the pivot body

```
Sub EmailSend()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application

    Dim olEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    With olEmail
        ' Recipients
        .To = "c_dpal###in@###.com.##"
        .CC = "c_dpal###in@###.com.##"
        
        ' Subject
        .Subject = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J3")
        
        ' Mail body
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .display                        ' display comes here so that the signature can be shown if it exists
        
        Dim strBody As String
        Dim PivotRng As Range
        Dim PivotFilterRng As Range: Set PivotFilterRng = ActiveSheet.Range("B4:C6")
        
        ' Greetings
        strBody = strBody & "Good Day Ms ###," & "<br><br>"
        strBody = strBody & "Please see performance as of today:" & "<br><br>"
        
        ' Pivot Filters
        strBody = strBody & RangetoHTML(PivotFilterRng)
        
        ' Pivot body
        Set PivotRng = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).TableRange1
        strBody = strBody & RangetoHTML(PivotRng) & "<br>"
        strBody = strBody & "Regards," & "<br>" & "####"
        
        ' Insert 'strBody'
        .HTMLBody = strBody & .HTMLBody
        
        ' Send mail
        '.send
    End With
End Sub
```

Ron de Bruin function

```
Function RangetoHTML(Rng As Range)
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    Rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         fileName:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```